# Update Array by Key

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, nosql

My schema goes like this

```
{
    info: {
        items: Number,
        someInteger: Number
    },
    items: [
        {
            itemId: Number,
            itemTime: Number
        }
    ]
}
```

And I'm trying to increment all of the values. I can increment for example info.items easily but I can't figure out how to increment items.$.itemTime for a given itemId without going for another update function call for each different itemIds. I thought this would be inefficient.

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: Did you mean for the second key (`items`) to contain an array of just one object?

Answer (score 0):

See comments inline.

```js
let obj = {
    info: {
        items: 2,
        someInteger: 4
    },
    items: [
        {
            itemId: 6,
            itemTime: 8
        }
    ]
};

function increment(obj, key, prop, index){
  // Check to see if the key passed holds an array
  if(obj[key] instanceof Array){
    // Use the index to get to the right child object
    obj[key][index][prop]++;
  } else {
    // Just increment the property
    obj[key][prop]++;
  }

}

increment(obj, "items", "itemTime", 0);
increment(obj, "info", "items");
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate the entries of the object and check if the value is another object, then iterate the nested object. Otherwise call the function and update the property.

```js
function update(object, fn) {
    Object
        .entries(object)
        .forEach(([k, v]) => {
            if (v && typeof v === 'object') {
                update(v, fn);
                return;
            }
            object[k] = fn(v);
        });
}

var data = { info: { items: 1, someInteger: 2 }, items: [{ itemId: 3, itemTime: 4 }] };

update(data, v => v + 1);

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```